# Samsung GT-i8262 only boots into recovery after flashing

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

I have issue with this phone, flashed the recovery to CWM using the Rashr application and rebooted. Now my phone only boots into recovery anytime I turn it on.

The USB port is damaged, now I decided to flash with CyanogenMod but no avail.

Comment: What happens when you try to install cyanogenmod? Any error message or does it just not boot? Which partitions have you wiped before flashing CM?

Comment: No error messages, did successfully. Wiped data/cache and Davlik

Comment: Try wiping the system partition before flashing. The flashable zip file should do that most likely automatically but you never know :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your battery and  open download mode manually by pressing Power button+Home+volume down key. If you do like this, only then, download mode will support your Odin otherwise, it won’t support. After this just flash your CWM recovery again.

**EDIT:** 
You just need to re-flash recovery. In your case, you can use your CWM recovery to flash. I don't remember that it will work. But you can surely flash [this](http://bit.ly/2dlwBAd)
TWRP recovery.

There is a bug which comes in effect if you use reboot from CWM recovery menu. Beware of that bug and reboot manually.

See [this](http://bit.ly/2cyuyrC) and [this](http://bit.ly/2dejz6j) for any help about rooting or any problem.

Comment: His USB Port is defective, he is not able to use download mode / Odin to flash a new recovery image.

Comment: "my phone only boots into recovery anytime I turn it on" – so how to use Rashr then with the device not fully powering up? Isn't Rashr an app?

Comment: Ye, thanks. My USB port has spoilt. I'm asking if there is a way to flash recovery using the existing CWM recovery.

Comment: Flash that twrp up there from cwm recovery. Works fine.